# Relativistic fomulae for energy and momentum?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, momentum

I know that the relativistic formulae for energy and momentum are:

$E = \gamma mc^2$ and $\textbf{p} = \gamma m\textbf{v}$;

Can we derive these formulae?

If yes, where from?

Comment: If you are satisfied with the energy and momentum forming a four-vector then you could start with a particle at rest which must have zero momentum and only mass energy, i.e., $p_\mu = (mc^2,0,0,0)$. Then you could just boost this relation and find the energy and 3-momentum after the transformation.

Comment: Why was the question down-voted?  @JeffDror, why did you make this a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: @garyp: I guess I should have. I wasn't sure if my answer was "fundamental enough".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once we have the position 4-vector
$$x^\mu=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
ct\\
\vec{x}\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
It is natural to define the momentum and energy in a fashion which is analogous to the Newtonian case (and reduces to it in the frame of the particle itself, when $\vec{v}=0$:
$$
p^\mu \equiv
m\frac{d}{d\tau}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
ct\\
\vec{x}\\
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
E/c\\
\vec{p}\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where $\tau=\frac{t}{\gamma}$ is the eigentime. This immediately leads to your formula's
$$\vec{p}=\gamma m\vec{v}\hspace{2cm}E=\gamma mc^2$$
I hope this semi-first principles version is satisfactory.